# Who will garbage collect or unload the garbage collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, garbage

After finishing the java program the `young gen`, `old gen`, `perm gen` will be full garbage collected, And here garbage collector is also a program, so who will do the garbage collection for the garbage collector? or will it exit just like that?

Comment: Even if the GC is to be conceived of as an object occupying memory, one would first have to ask the same thing about permanent objects... In other words, some things just live on, until the JVM process ends

Comment: It's not guaranteed that the GC is run on shutdown. When a process exists, all it's resources are recycled by the OS.

Comment: @GhostCat you are welcome! I found one point, when jvm itself is shutting down, there is no need of freeing up the memory, it will be handed over to OS.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You are right!

Comment: @PeterLawrey to be more precise, we can place high bets on the assumption that the garbage collector will *not* run on shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start any process, the memory for that is coming from the operating system.

When that process ends, all of the memory goes back to that operating system.

So, the second the jvm process ends, all its memory becomes "free" again.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is based on a couple of misunderstandings.

> After finishing the java program the young gen, old gen, perm gen will be full garbage collected.

That is not what happens.

When the Java program finishes, the JVM exits.  When that happens, the JVM process exits, and its address space is reclaimed by the OS.  At that point, the entire heap (which is in the JVM processes address space) simply ceases to exist.

Objects are not garbage collected, or finalized, or whatever.  Instead, the memory that held the object representations has been taken back by the OS, and will never be seen again<sup>1</sup>.

> And here garbage collector is also a program, so who will do the garbage collection for the garbage collector? or will it exit just like that?

The garbage collector is not a program.

- It is builtin functionality of the JVM.
- It is implemented in native code, not Java.
- When it is finish a GC cycle, it doesn't exit.  Instead, it goes to sleep until the next time it is needed.
- If the GC allocates heap memory (which is doubtful<sup>2</sup>), then that memory will remain in use until the next time the GC runs.

---

<sup>1 - That is ... unless you can convince the operating system to give it to you; e.g. in the form of a "core dump", or by poking around in the virtual memory system prior to the pages being zeroed.</sup>

<sup>2 - It possible that the GC will allocate heap objects to hold GC stats or GC log message ... but I think it uses non-heap memory for those things.  Either way, the amount memory allocated for these purposes should be too small to care about.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

When your Java program finished your JVM will be `exit/shutdown` and the entire memory taken by the `JVM` will be free. So, there is no need to `GC` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The Garbage Collector is part of the Java Virtual Machine, which is doing a lot more, then just garbage collection. In the moment your program ends, the entire machine is shutting down and frees all the used memory (including the garbage collector)